Greasepencil Lineart accumulating strokes opacity (Greasepencil uniform opacity <100%)
Objective:

Achieve uniform lineart opacity below 100%.
(without overlapping strokes - creating accumulated higher opacity)

Non working methods tried:

Lineart opacity

Opacity modifier after Lineart modifier

Stroke material alpha

Chaining

Edge types


Working methods tried

Compositor separate layer opacity, obv.

Is there a method how to achieve lineart with uniform opacity <100% without using compositor?
Seems that "Opacity modifier->Uniform Opacity" is meant to do the trick, but it doesnt.


Is there a motivation for not using the compositor ? Some things are only possible with compositing.

Yup not sure it's possible without a post processing effect, the opacity is working like intended there, strokes overlap so opacity adds up

Have you tried the most basic Layer Opacity? That works fine on my end.

I didn't even have to turn on Compositor nodes to render stroke opacity.
In my case, I set my background to Transparent and gave my mesh with the line art modifier a Holdout mask.
